# <textarea/> tag "swallows" html

Tags: html

This is a very strange problem I've been struggling with for a few days. At first I thought it was related to something in our application, but I've stripped it down to the simplest html page and it's still happening. Basically anytime I add a  tag to a page the html after it gets rendered as it's value. `<textarea></textarea>` fixes the issue, but I don't understand why. I'm at a loss here, it has to be something really simple that I just don't know.

In the following example the paragraph tags show up as the value of the textarea.

I'm using IE8.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>About</title>
</head>
<body>

    <textarea/>
        <p align="center">
            test
        </p>
        <p align="left">
           test
        </p>


</body>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`<textarea>` is not a self-closing tag. It should be re-written as `<textarea></textarea>`

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming you trying to have the paragraphs appear after the textarea.  Try not using the textarea tag as an empty tag.

```
<textarea></textarea>

<p align="center">
    test
</p>
<p align="left">
   test
</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe Textarea requires an opening and closing tag - at least that's how it's presented here:
[textarea at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)

Comment: I've found HTML Dog to be pretty useful myself, so if anyone want's an alternative to W3Schools (not associated with W3 **and** uses a `<table>` for their layout! NOOOO!), here's a link: http://www.htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/textarea/

Comment: See, I figured it was something like that, but they don't really state that anywhere I could find, on either site. And the validators in VS2010 don't complain about it. My real issue is this textarea is in xslt, and when it gets transformed it's rendered as <textarea/> automatically. I guess that's for another question though!

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem too. I realized I had forgotten to give a name attribute to my `textarea` like I did all my other inputs so that the PHP script could collect it all and send it to an SQL table.

Once I gave it a name, it magically stopped chopping off the closing tag and making it a self closing tag which got ignored by the browser until it bumped into the closing tag of a `textarea` with a name attribute, swallowing up everything in between.  Hopefully this sheds more light on the issue too, as putting text in between the closing tags wasn't an ideal option for me.