# Echo var from PHP into textarea control

Tags: php

Desired outcome: define string var in PHP and echo it into textarea control as contents.

Problem: Textarea only contains:

```
    </body>
</html>
```

INDEX.PHP:

```
<?php
    $y = "Bonkers";
?>
<html>
<body>

    Here is a textarea control:<br />
    <textarea id='myText'  rows="30" cols="120" value='<?php echo $y; ?>' />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read up on HTML http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<textarea>` doesn't have an HTML value attribute. Therefore, the correct way to set text within a textarea is as follows:

```
<textarea id="myText" rows="30" cols="120"><?php echo $y; ?></textarea>
```

You can access it within JavaScript or jQuery, however, as you would a normal input field.

```
// jQuery example
$("textarea#myText").val();
```

The reason why your textarea contains the ending body and html tags is due to how `<textarea>` is closed; it's only meant to be used as `<textarea></textarea>`, not `<textarea />`. ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665833/textarea-tag-swallows-html))

Comment: don't forget about htmlspecialchars https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112000/do-i-even-need-htmlspecialchars-for-textareas-value
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632660/how-to-keep-text-inserted-in-a-html-textarea-after-a-wrong-submission

Answer (score 12):

The textarea element doesn't have a value attribute. This is how you should do it:

```
<textarea id='myText'  rows="30" cols="120"><?php echo $y; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Oh for Pete's sake... I copied someone else's code and just assumed...  Thanks gents.

Comment: So why the weird behavior... Why not nothing (a blank textarea on page)?

Comment: Basically, it's because textarea isn't meant to be self-closing. Therefore, it reads the rest of the page looking for the closing textarea tag. That's why `</body></html>` appear within the textarea.

Comment: Because you're not terminating your text area. Without a closing </textarea> html tag, it's going to assume everything after the initial tag needs to be in the <textarea>

Answer (score 0):

Do You Know !! You can echo something in textarea by using placeholder attribute also. Code is as follow.

```
<textarea placeholder="<?php echo $_SESSION['your_name']; ?>"></textarea>
```

Comment: This won't actually put the text in the text area, it will only display the text until someone types something