# do I even need `htmlspecialchars()` for textarea's value

Tags: php, xss, htmlspecialchars

I have `staff.php` page which contains staff's name,position and detail.When user would need to edit staff info,they would be send to `edit.php` page.`edit.php` page show name and title on `text field` and detail on a `textarea`

My question is,do I even need `htmlspecialchars` in `edit.php` page.I am not printing anything to users page,only on that fields.But I'm using `htmlspecialchars` on `staff.php` before printing to user.

Is it still open to `XSS Attack`?

**Code**

*part from `staff.php`*

```
$staff.="<div id='sob'>".htmlspecialchars($title)."<br>".htmlspecialchars($sub_title)."<div><a href='edit.php?pid=".htmlspecialchars($pro_id)."'><input type='submit' id='editx' name='editx' value='Edit'></a></div><div id=''><br>".htmlspecialchars($detail)."</div><hr id='h'></div>";
```

*part from `edit.php`*

```
if(isset($_GET["pid"])){
  $name4=$title;            //
  $sub_title4=$sub_title;   //using prepared statement  
  $detail4=$detail;         //
  }

  HTML part at edit.php

 <input type='text' id='staff_name' name='staff_name' value="<?php echo $name4;?>" required>
 </br><input type='text' id='staff_pos' name='staff_pos' value="<?php echo $sub_title4;?>" required>
 </br><textarea id='staff_detail' name='staff_detail' cols='30' rows='6'  required><?php echo $detail4;?></textarea></br>
```

Comment: Yes, because if the value of `$detail4` was `</textarea><script>alert("XSS!");</script>` it would be vulnerable.

Comment: For the `<input>` tags with variables in `value=` you also need to use it with the `ENT_QUOTES` option, to prevent a quote inside the variable from closing the `value=` attribute and breaking your HTML.  `value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name4, ENT_QUOTES); ?>"`

Comment: Okay,that make sense.As I found from most blog,I though `XSS` might only occur when print to screen.

Comment: Placing variables inside form values _is_ printing them to the screen, even though they are not directly output. A better way to put it is _any time you are using PHP values from user input to generate HTML markup_

Comment: but I want to allow `single quote`.Is it ok,if I use the default one `ENT_COMPAT`

Comment: ENT_COMPAT is fine if you consistently use double quotes for the attributes.

Comment: _“but I want to allow single quote”_ – using `htmlspecialchars` is not about allowing (or in turn, “forbidding”) something – it is about making what _is_ allowed safe for being output as HTML.

Comment: Thanks a lot,man.Hats off.If you want to add this as an answer,I would be more than happy to accept it.Because I've learnt something new

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Protection against XSS isn't just necessary  when variables are to be *displayed* on the screen; it is needed whenever user-generated values are used to build HTML markup, whatever the context.

It *is* necessary to call `htmlspecialchars()` on a PHP variable placed inside a `<textarea>`. Consider the following:

```
<?php
    // Unsafe text in the variable
    $detail4 = '</textarea><script>alert("XSS!");</script>';
?>

<textarea><?php echo $detail4; ?></textarea>
```

This results in a closed `</textarea>` followed by an unsafe injected script (and another closing `</textarea>` the browser will probably ignore).

It is also necessary to call `htmlspecialchars()` on the variables placed into `value=""` attributes, choosing the appropriate constant to ensure internal quotes in the variables are correctly encoded to prevent the attribute being prematurely ended with a quote.  If you consistently use double quotes on the attributes, you can accept the default of `ENT_COMPAT`, but if you sometimes quote attributes with single quotes, use `ENT_QUOTE`.

```
<input type='text' name='staff_pos' value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($sub_title4, ENT_QUOTES);?>" ...>
```